# Backbone.js Router implementation

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm new to Backbone.js and don't exactly understand difference between some types of router implementation.

**1. Type:**

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes:{
            '*filter': 'setFilter'
        },

        setFilter: function( param ) {
            // Set the current filter to be used
            Common.TodoFilter = param.trim() || '';

            // Trigger a collection filter event, causing hiding/unhiding
            // of the Todo view items
            Todos.trigger('filter');
        }
    });
```

**2. Type:**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

        routes: {
            // default
            '*actions': 'defaultAction'
        }

    });

    var initialize = function() {

        var router = new AppRouter();

        router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions) {

            var homeView = new HomeView();
            homeView.render();

        });

        Backbone.history.start();

    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
```

So, what is the difference between normal callback (setFilter) in type 1 and function router.on('route:defaultAction', function(actions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Backbone [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> **"route:[name]" (params)** — Fired by the router when a specific route is matched.

So the `router.on('route:defaultAction'...` way is binding into event fired by the Router every time a route is matched.  There is no need for a callback in the Router itself, but the route must be defined in the routes-hash or with a route -function call.

The first way is the most basic way to match routes to functions, with [the `routes` -object](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes).

> The routes hash maps URLs with parameters to functions on your router

Hope this helps!